# What is the difference between passing a container directly vs as a reference into a function?

Tags: c++, function, containers

Why does it seem like the set is not one-to-one copied when passed as an argument? I suppose it has something to do with the fact that the iterator points at the original set whereas a new copied set is created. So the s.end() would point to the end pointer of the copied set and not the original set. But I don't understand the non terminating output below.

Why does this give an output of "-812375757575757575...":

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>

void f (std::set<int>::iterator itr, std::set<int> s) 
{
    if (itr != s.end()) 
    {
        std::cout << *itr;
        ++itr;
        f(itr, s);
    }
}

int main() 
{
    std::set<int> s {1, 2, 3, 7, -8};
    f(s.begin(), s);
    return 0;
}
```

Whereas this gives an output of "-81237":

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>

void f (std::set<int>::iterator itr, std::set<int>& s)
{
    if (itr != s.end()) 
    {
        std::cout << *itr;
        ++itr;
        f(itr, s);
    }
}

int main() 
{
    std::set<int> s {1, 2, 3, 7, -8};
    f(s.begin(), s);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `void f (std::set<int>::iterator itr, std::set<int> s) {` causes a copy to be made which could be expensive (time and space consuming) if `s` contains many items. `if (itr != s.end()) {` is a bug in the first function because itr is an iterator of a different container so you can't compare these.

Comment: `if (itr != s.end())` is invalid in the first example. The iterator is not from `f::s`, it is from `main::s`. `s` in `f()` is a copy, not a reference.

Comment: "I suppose it has something to do with the fact that the iterator points at the original set whereas a new copied set is created" its just that. Its undefined behavior because you cannot reach another containers `end` by incrementing iterator

Comment: Most standard C++ library implementations do not verify that iterators belong to the same container.  Those that do are by opt-in, intended for use in a debug build rather than an optimized release build.  And such extra instrumentation will probably also not be ABI compatible between opt-in and opt-out.  I find that to be an unfortunate circumstance, but, alas, it is the state of the C++ industry.

Comment: I just wanted to say that what OP refers to as "passing directly" is anything but.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first code exhibits **undefined behavior**, hence the erroneous output.

On each call to `f()`, the `s` parameter is being passed in *by value*, which means a **copy** of the caller's `set` object is being made.  As such, you end up comparing iterators that don't belong to the same `set` object, which is *undefined behavior*.  In your case, your loop does not end when you expect it to, causing the iterator to eventually go beyond the bounds of the original `set` object into memory that doesn't belong to the original `set`.  That is where the erroneous output values are coming from.

The second code fixes that issue by passing the `s` parameter *by reference* instead, so no copies are ever made, and thus iterators that belong to the same `set` object are compared, and the loop ends when expected.  No *undefined behavior*.

Comment: Where does the 5 come from in the erroneous output?

Comment: @ilsec I have updated my answer to explain that

Comment: The iterator seems to kind of go back and forth between the last element and s.end(). I guess it is because of how the iterator increment is programmed?

Comment: @ilsec **Undefined behavior** is undefined behavior. Don't try to make sense of it. Just fix it so the behavior is well-defined.